# Django attempts to connect to wrong socket

Tags: python, mysql, django, google-cloud-sql, unix-socket

I am attempting to set up django to connect to google cloud sql following the instructions found here: [Connecting MySQL Client Using the Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-connect-proxy#enable-api).
After I start the proxy with:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql -instances=my-instance -credential_file=/app/keyfile.json > /logs/proxy.txt &
```

Django fails to connect to the db, and gives this error when you try to load a page:

> (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")

I'm new to unix sockets so I could be interpreting this incorrectly, but it appears to me that django is trying to connect to a socket at /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock.

My database configuration in Django is:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'HOSTS': '/cloudsql/my-instance-description',
        'NAME': 'main',
        'USER': '****',
        'PASSWORD': '****',
    }
}
```

Am I interpreting this correctly?  If so, what do I need to change so that django tries to connect to the socket at /cloudsql/my-instance-description rather than the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is a typo. Use `HOST` instead of `HOSTS`.

Comment: Dang it, you're absolutely right.  Should I delete the question?