# How do I connect to Google Cloud mySQL from App Engine using Django-Environ?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, django-settings, django-environ

I am trying to connect a Django Google App engine to an instance of Cloud Mysql using django-environ.  The app is unable to connect to the database, but otherwise runs successfully.

I have followed the Django tutorials for connecting to a cloudsql instance, and referenced the django-environ documentation regarding the connection string.  The connection is successful from my local machine, but fails when running in the app engine environment.

My settings.py file shows:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': env.db()
,}
```

I have tried over 20 patterns for the DATABASE_URL based on the documentation, but none have been successful.
I am setting these as environment variables using google secrets manager, and I have verified that they are being pulled to the program and set as environment variables correctly.

The documentation shows mysql://user:password@host:port/dbname.  I have tried this using the public IP address and port 3306.  (Works on my machine).
I have also tried replacing 'host:port' with the connection string and with /cloudsql/.
some other combinations I have tried:

`mysql://user:password@127.0.0.1:3306/dbname`
`mysql://user:password@127.0.0.1:5432/dbname`
`mysql://user:password@//cloudsql/<connection string/dbname`

So far nothing has been successful.
I have added the IAM role of SQL Client to my app engine service account.

EDIT: enocom's response was what ended up working.  I had tried the same configuration many times, but I think it was something in the Cloud Console security that might have been preventing it from working.  The only think that I'm sure was different is that I activated the Cloud SQL Admin API.  Is that a requirement for this type of connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'HOST': '/cloudsql/myproject:us-central1:myinstance',
        'NAME': 'main',
        'USER': '****',
        'PASSWORD': '****',
    }
}
```

From [Django attempts to connect to wrong socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41640470/django-attempts-to-connect-to-wrong-socket)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say if this was Google App Engine Standard or if it's flex.

[This](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard) is the documentation for connecting to Google App Engine Standard. You can connect with one of Unix Sockets or Cloud SQL connectors

See [sample code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/main/cloud-sql/mysql/sqlalchemy/README.md) from Google on GitHub